# AWS CLI describe-instances does not return any instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have one t2.micro instance running in AWS EC2.
I tried to list the instance with AWS CLI but the result seems to be empty.
Any hint?

```
[root@centos7 ~]# aws ec2 describe-instances
{
    "Reservations": []
}
```

Comment: Check your cli, your must have configured while configuring aws cli. Your EC2 might not be in default region, if still this problem persist try checking your ass profile, a wrong account may be used for querying if you have mutiple profiles

Comment: I noticed that almost all your questions have answers, yet not a single one accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances for your questions to be actually answered.

Answer (score 5):

You might have the instance in another region compared to the default region in your cli.

```sh
aws ec2 describe-instances --region YOUR_REGION_NAME
```

Comment: @idiotone If it works, then the answer should be accepted.

Comment: had the same problem and it was solved with this suggestion.